# Move-Item -Exclude -Recursive Is Not leaving excluded items in place within sub directories

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to move all items except a certain type of file.  In this case *.msg.  It does fine if the excluded file resides within the parent folder.  However, the moment that same type of file is located within a subdirectory, it fails to leave the file in place and instead moves it to the new location.

```
username = Get-Content '.\users.txt'
foreach ($un in $username)
{
  $destA = "c:\users\$un\redirectedfolders\mydocuments"
  $destB = "c:\users\$un\redirectedfolders\desktop"
  $sourceA = "C:\users\$un\mydocuments"
  $sourceB = "C:\users\$un\desktop"

  New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $destA, $destB

  Get-ChildItem $sourceA -Exclude '*.msg' -Recurse | Move-Item -Destination {Join-Path $destA $_.FullName.Substring($sourceA.length)}
  Get-ChildItem $sourceB -Exclude '*.msg' -Recurse | Move-Item -Destination {Join-Path $destB $_.FullName.Substring($sourceB.length)}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the filtering done by the Get-ChildItem exclude filter. It's kind of a known issue, and if you really want I could probably dig up some reference documentation, but it may take some time. Regardless, GCI doesn't handle wildcards very well when it comes to filtering things. What you are probably better off doing is piping it to a Where command like this:

```
$username = Get-Content '.\users.txt'
foreach ($un in $username)
{
  $destA = "c:\users\$un\redirectedfolders\documents"
  $destB = "c:\users\$un\redirectedfolders\desktop"
  $sourceA = "C:\users\$un\documents"
  $sourceB = "C:\users\$un\desktop"

  New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $destA, $destB
  GCI $sourceA -recurse | ?{$_.Extension -ne ".msg" -and !$_.PSIsContainer} | %{
    $CurDest = Join-Path $destA $_.FullName.Substring($sourceA.length)
    If(!(Test-Path $CurDest.SubString(0,$CurDest.LastIndexOf("\")))){New-Item -Path $CurDest -ItemType Directory|Out-Null}
    $_ | Move-Item -Destination $CurDest
  }
  GCI $sourceB -recurse | ?{$_.Extension -ne ".msg" -and !$_.PSIsContainer} | %{
    $CurDest = Join-Path $destB $_.FullName.Substring($sourceB.length)
    If(!(Test-Path $CurDest.SubString(0,$CurDest.LastIndexOf("\")))){New-Item -Path $CurDest -ItemType Directory|Out-Null}
    $_ | Move-Item -Destination $CurDest
  }
}
```

**Edit:** Ok, now excludes folders, and also keeps folder structure.
**Edit2:** Re-designed to do a ForEach loop on the files, build the destination path as `$CurDest`, test to make sure it exists and make it if it doesn't, then move the files. Also changed `mydocuments` to `documents` which is the path to a user's My Documents folder.

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for your response.  I retried it using the new code.  it still moved the msg file i had buried in a child folder.  I'm not sure why.   :(  Sometimes depending on the user.  They will have hundreds of msg files that we are trying to exclude.

Comment: I retried it with the . in front of the msg for the extension.  I only copied the two GCI rows.  It's still oddly moving them.  My assumption is that the move-item command is moving the entire subfolder where i planted a test.msg, because it receives the ok to move the subfolder.  I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks.  This time it kept the folders in place where i planted a test.msg.  However, it did not recreate the folder structure for the remaining items that were moved within the same subfolder where the test.msg was located.  Oddly, it also removed the file extension for one file, and truncated the file name of another leaving only the file extension as the name.

Comment: i put a -whatif after the move-item section.  It's exactly what i want to move.  But because we exclude the subdirector in the where command, it complains with this error. "Move-Item : Could not find a part of the path.  WriteError: (C:\users\99688482\desktop\test\test.txt:FileInfo) [Move-Item], DirectoryNotFoundException"    It's not recreating the folder structure if a *.msg was found in one of the subdirectories for the remaining of the files that do need to be moved.

Comment: Answer updated with re-designed script, and comments cleaned. Tested on my own laptop, and made sure it works.

Comment: Thank you for all your help.  Worked like a charm.  I'm still a rookie, so now to decipher what all the new code means.  :)  Thanks again!

Comment: If you have questions about something specific in there let me know and I'll explain it.